# Why CORS error happens even if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present in OPTIONS response in AWS lambda trigger (API Gateway of REST API)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm mad. Why error  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` still raises even if `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` is present in preflight response?

this is my configure:

## AWS lambda function backend code (nodejs):

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (event.httpMethod == 'OPTIONS') {
    return {
      headers: {
        "foo": "bar",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
      },
      statusCode: 200,
    }
  }
  if (!event.body) {
    throw new Error("no body provided")
  }
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
  if (!body.statement) {
    throw new Error("no statement provided")
  }
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  const [results] = await connection.query(body.statement)
  connection.end();

  let response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    body: JSON.stringify(results)
  };
  return response;
};
```

## this is the trigger configure (API Gateway of REST API)

```
API Gateway: planetscale-API
arn:aws:execute-api:ap-northeast-1:288496770745:832iyue4j2/*/*/planetscale
API endpoint: https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale
Details
API type: REST
Authorization: NONE
Method: ANY
Resource path: /planetscale
Service principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
Stage: default
Statement ID: lambda-11567109-822a-4850-abcf-14a1b0565c54
```

## and this is the js code:

```
await axios.post("https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale", { statement:"select * from t" });
```

## this is what happend in chrome network

### 1.preflight request

```
Request URL: https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:64646
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS,POST,GET
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 0
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 09:24:19 GMT
x-amz-apigw-id: WlsmmH0mNjMFZGA=
x-amzn-requestid: d25ff521-94ee-48d2-bc33-68bb92495b42
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-62f227c3-14547cf1741c86e83d846763;Sampled=0
xxxx: aaaa
:authority: 832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /default/planetscale
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: http://localhost:8080
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

### 2. POST request

```
Request URL: https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 502 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-length: 36
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 09:24:20 GMT
x-amz-apigw-id: WlsmpE_HtjMFmfw=
x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException
x-amzn-requestid: a3f991a8-1f6b-445f-b5db-697c7efaa1f8
:authority: 832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
:method: POST
:path: /default/planetscale
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
content-length: 50
content-type: application/json
origin: http://localhost:8080
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

## this is what happends in chrome console :

```
localhost/:1 
        
       Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
App.vue?18cf:151 error aws lambda
xhr.js?ed5b:220 
        
      
        
        
      
        
      
       
        
       POST https://832iyue4j2.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/planetscale net::ERR_FAILED 502
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?ed5b:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?ed5b:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?d0b9:58
request @ Axios.js?3509:109
httpMethod @ Axios.js?3509:144
wrap @ bind.js?285c:9
Comment.query @ models.js?a3ef:37
exec @ modelsql.mjs?8304:626
download @ App.vue?18cf:149
tryDownload @ App.vue?18cf:200
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?3841:2988
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?3841:1786
original_1._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?3841:7405
```

Comment: You're getting a 502 error on POST, which means that your Lambda function is probably broken somewhere and it's not returning properly. You probably have some exception that causes the Lambda function to return the improper response. Check Lambda function execution logs to see if there's anything logged.

Comment: @Caldazar Thanks. Indeed. I add `Access-Control-Allow-*` to all my responses (OPTIONS and POST) and problem solved